# Find String, then replace next 5 characters

Tags: vba

I require some VBA code that can find a string in the middle of a cell([EPM-BPM-), then delete the last 6 characters in the overall cell and then add an * to the end. I have tried many different methods but nothing has worked. Below is an image explaining what I am attempting.

[Example Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gORSL.png)

Comment: Could you please provide the methods you have attempted and what was the input value tried and what was expected?. Also, I request you to check [Creating Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Replace()` method of `Range` object:

```
Sub main()

    Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Replace "EPM-BPM-*]", "EPM-BPM-" & Chr(42) & "]", lookat:=xlPart

End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!